# COM port seems busy all the time

Tags: arduino, serial-port, processing

I'm having problems with Processing3, where when I attempt to connect to a certain COM port, the app crashes, with the Port Busy error.

Here's the code snippet:

```java
boolean found = false;
text(Arrays.toString(Serial.list()), 20, 500);
println("Still checking...");
for (String port : Serial.list()) {
  myPort = new Serial(this, port);
  myPort.clear();
  myPort.write("init\n");
  if (myPort.readStringUntil(lf) == "connected") {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (!found) {
  myPort = emptyPort;
  text("Waiting for device...", 20, 40);
}
```

This is part of the draw() loop, the error is thrown at line 5 in this example. Until that particular port becomes available, everything else is running just fine.

This is the setup() code from the connected arduino:

```java
Serial.begin(256000);
while (!Serial.available()) {}
while (true) {
  String recv = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (recv == "init") {
    Serial.println("connected");
    break;
  } else {
    while (!Serial.available()) {}
  }
}
Serial.println("600,400");
```

Testing from the Serial Monitor in Arduino IDE produces no such error.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Oh yeah, I was waiting for SO to let me accept my own answer, and in the meantime, kinda forgot about it.. Moved onto other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replacing myPort with emptyPort, you should close myPort and free up the COM port for repeated connection by doing myPort.stop().

Answer (score 0):

This seems wrong:

```java
for (String port : Serial.list()) {
  myPort = new Serial(this, port);
```

Here you're connecting to **every** serial port. You should probably just connect to one, right?

Also, you said you're doing this from the `draw()` function? That also seems wrong. You don't want to connect to the port 60 times per second. You want to connect to it **once** from the `setup()` function and then just use that connection for the rest of the program.

If I were you, I would go back and look at some code examples.

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/Serial.html):

```java
// Example by Tom Igoe

import processing.serial.*;

// The serial port:
Serial myPort;       

// List all the available serial ports:
printArray(Serial.list());

// Open the port you are using at the rate you want:
myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);

// Send a capital A out the serial port:
myPort.write(65);
```

This example just connects to the first COM port it finds, then sends a single value. Note that this code is "once and done" and isn't repeated, similar to what would happen if you put this all in the `setup()` function.

Get something simple like this working before trying to move onto something more complicated. If you get stuck, then post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a bunch of disconnected snippets. Good luck.

Comment: Due to other problems, where there may be multiple ports, and I need to figure out which one to connect to by connecting to it, sending a string, expecting another string... So yes, I need to try to connect to every serial port, even though in this case, only one is available anyways.

Comment: I also want to periodically check ports, if a connection hasn't been established yet.

Comment: @JanNovák I see. I still don't think you should do this from the `draw()` function, and I still think you should try getting something simpler working and posting a [mcve].

Comment: So, yes, I want to connect to all available ports, if required, and repeat it as many times as required.

Comment: @JanNovák Maybe. But right now you're trying to connect 60 times per second. It doesn't surprise me that your com port is busy. You should only reconnect when there isn't a connection. Not 60 times per second.

Comment: Well, this code snippet is run only if a connection hasn't been established yet. And the particular COM port that's throwing this error, is actually the one it should establish on. Also, why I have to run it in draw() is because as you can tell, I am drawing on the screen, which a while loop in setup() can't.

Comment: @JanNovák Please post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet. And a `while` loop in `setup()` can draw to the screen. But it doesn't matter, because my point stands. It's up to you how you want to proceed.